# Does Django's form framework use the Django messages framework?

Tags: python, django, forms, message

I'm using django-registration and getting an introduction to Django's form framework. I've been using the `.to_p()` method to display forms, but I need a better way of presenting the form data, so I'm reading up on the forms framework.

Do errors passed by the form framework get passed to [Django's messages framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're completely separate - as they should be, as messages is in `django.contrib` and therefore can't be guaranteed to be enabled.

The best way to show errors is within the form itself, as the `as_p` method does. I use a template tag to display each field with its associated errors in one go - it's a modified version of Peter Baumgartner's [display_field tag](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/13/better-newforms).

Answer (score 2):

Each field of a form has its own error messages stored in a dictionary... So

```
class MyForm(Form):
    myfield = CharField()
    nullfield = CharField(blank=True)
```

After your validation step, if some form errors had been detected, they all stored in the errors dictionary so,

```
form = MyForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    ...
else:
    # assert form errors
    assert 0, form.errors
```

form errors dictionary will be like

```
{'myfield': [u'This field is required.']}
```

So, each error will be added to the errors dictionary. 
You can check that dictionary and create a single error message, or whatever you want to do in your view. Or in the template you can iterate through them with

```
{%for err in form.errors%}
    ........
{%endfor %}
```

Ans as you see, there is nothing about django messages application... If you really wish to pass those error messages to django messages application, you may try

```
for error in form.errors:
    request.user.message_set.create(message=form.errors['error'])
```

Comment: A quote form Steve Mconell: Normally, you don't want users to see assertion messages in production code; assertions are primarily for use during development and maintenance. Assertions are normally compiled into the code at development time and compiled out of the code for production.

Answer (score 0):

No, not automatically. You will have to handle that yourself.

```
 if not form.is_valid():
     # loop through form.errors and
     # convert that in messages.error
     # where appropriate
```

Comment: Kind of a pain, because django-registration is already an 'app' so i can't really modify it. Any suggestions on how to add the errors to the messages framework?